# How to use synonyms functionality in open search server

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine

I am trying to use the Synonyms functionality in opensearchserver (http://open-search-server.com). i have created a list for instance,
ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod, i-pod, i pod
It is not working. can any one tell me how to make it work with opensearchserver.

Comment: Share some code with us please :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process to setup synonyms in OpenSearchServer.

1. Create the synonym list in the tab panel /Schema/synonyms.
   One line per group of equivalent words separated by commas:

Example:

```
ipod,i pod,epod,e pod
opensearchserver,open search server
```

2. Setup the analyzers to use the synonym list.

   - Go to the tab panel /Schema/Analyzers.
   - Edit the analyzer which will handle the synonyms. If you use the default schema template you should edit the StandardAnalyzer.
     Here is a screenshot capture which show the correct setup. To be multi-term aware, we have to add a shingle filter to build group of words. the synonym filter.
3. Reindex your data.

You can now search for ipod, i-pod, epod, e-pod, and find any ipod!

Remark:
I removed the dash version (i-pod) because when you use the StandardAnalyzer, the dash are already ignored.[image]

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to automate this process? I have a Big index with more than 1.500.000 documents and need to use the did you mean feature in Title.